# JFrame arranging buttons using GridBagLayout

Tags: java, swing, layout, jbutton, layout-manager

Here's example:

```
    help = new JButton("Help");
    setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
    c.gridx = 50;
    c.gridy = 50;
    add(help,c);
```

I may be understanding this wrong (I got this concept from some tutorials on `youtube`) and I can't seem to get my "Help" button to where it needs to be. No matter what I change the `gridx` or `gridy` to, the button always stays in the middle. If this part of the code isn't sufficient enough, let me know and I can post the entire thing though I think this should be enough.

Comment: can you post a sample output that you want to show?

Comment: *"If this part of the code isn't sufficient enough, let me know and I can post the entire thing.."*  I recommend a 3rd option.  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  Provide ASCII art of the GUI as it should appear in smallest size and (if resizable) with extra width/height.

Comment: @JavaLearner I just want to be able to position the button anywhere on the screen basically.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html Read about property `anchor`. I think it may be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Let me explain a bit about GridbagLayout (greatly simplified).

Just think about a chessboard, where you have 8 columns and 8 rows = 64 cells. In every cell you can put an ui-element, like your button. Now if you set gridx=3 and gridy=1 that would put the button in the 2nd column of the 4th row on your chess board.

The thing is: Unlike in a chessboard your cells don't have equal height or width. If you put a large element in column 3, the whole column will be bigger. If you have no element in the first column (like in this case) it's width will be 0. So your can set gridx to 50 or whatever, if all columns before that don't contain elements, your button will still be the first element on the left side

Try `c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;`

Answer (score -2):

Your code above is really insufficient to see what's going on. If you're using Eclipse IDE I recommend to install [WindowBuilder](https://www.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/) plugin to fix your layout using a GUI. It's much easier :)

Comment: Using a window builder is really only effective once you know ***how*** to use the layouts.  Bad suggestion..